# Questions on change of coordinates with respect to orthonormal bases in $\;\mathbb R^2\;$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, orthogonal-matrices

> Let $\;U \subset \mathbb R^2\;$ be a smooth open domain. On
>   $\;\partial U\;$ consider the positively oriented orthonormal basis
>   $\;(\mathcal v,\mathcal τ)\;$ where $\;\mathcal v\;$ is the outer
>   normal and $\;\mathcal τ\;$ is the tangential vector.
>
> Fix $\;x\in \partial U\;$ and take $\;\{\mathcal v_x,\mathcal τ_x
>  \}\;$. Now fix this system and drop the subscript $\;x\;$.
>
> Let $\;x'\;$ be the coordinates of an arbitary vector in $\;\mathbb
>  R^2\;$ with respect to $\;\{\mathcal v,\mathcal τ\}\;$ and $\;A\;$ the  rotation: $\;x'=Ax\;$ where $\;A\;$ is orthogonal.

**I'm interested in finding:**

**1. The coordinates of $\;x'\;$ with respect to $\;\{\mathcal v,\mathcal τ\}\;$.**

**2. The coordinates of $A\mathcal v\;$**

**and understand the geometry behind these changes.**

*My attempt:*

Below I tried to picture the above as I understand them:

[image]
[image]

The coordinates of $\;x'\;$ with respcect to  $\;\{x_1,x_2\}\;$ are : $\;x'=(x_1,x_2)\;$ while the coordinates of $\;x'\;$ with respect to $\;\{\mathcal v,\mathcal τ\}\;$ should be: $\;x'=({x_1}',{x_2}')=(\langle x',\mathcal τ \rangle\;\langle x',\mathcal v \rangle)\;$ where $\;\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle \;$ stands for the Euclidean inner product.

**Questions:**

- Is the above visualization correct?
- Does the orthogonal transformation $\;x'=Ax\;$ represent the rotation of the axes $\;\{x_1,x_2\}\;$ to $\;\{\mathcal v,\mathcal τ\}\;$?
- What will $\;A\mathcal v\;$ be like?
- Except the rotaion of the axes, there is also a translation. Where did it show up?

All these coordinates and transformations confuse me a lot. I would really appreciate if someone could make all that clear to me.I apologize in advance if the above are quite elementary but I focused mostly on just solving equations in the past rather than understanding their geometric meaning (which is completely wrong).

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I wanna ask that which software have you used to draw these pictures?